# Stretch UIBarButtonItem to accommodate customView

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am placing a `UILabel` as the `customView` for a `UIBarButtonItem`. However, I need the button width to be dynamic to accommodate longer labels. At the moment it just truncates them. This is my code:

```
let participantCountLabel = UILabel()
participantCountLabel.text = "\(participantCount) participants"
self.toolbarLeftButton.customView = participantCountLabel
```

I think it may be because of the Flexible Space. Does that need to be resized?

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

This is the storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do:

```
let participantCountLabel = UILabel()
participantCountLabel.text = "\(participantCount) participants"
self.toolbarLeftButton.customView = participantCountLabel
self.toolbarLeftButton.customView.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way find width and height of text and then set label size

```
    var participantCountLabel: UILabel=UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 10, 40));
    participantCountLabel.text = "\(participantCount) participants"


    var strText:NSString=participantCountLabel.text!

    let styleLineBreakWordWrap :  NSMutableParagraphStyle=NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    styleLineBreakWordWrap.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    styleLineBreakWordWrap.alignment=NSTextAlignment.Left


    var attributes:NSDictionary=[NSFontAttributeName : participantCountLabel.font,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:styleLineBreakWordWrap]

    strText.sizeWithAttributes(attributes);

    var maximumLabelSize : CGSize=CGSizeMake(1000, 100)

    var textRect: CGRect=strText.boundingRectWithSize(maximumLabelSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)

    participantCountLabel.frame.size=textRect.size;

    self.toolbarLeftButton.customView = participantCountLabel
```